# How to insert a legend in 'menu' function in matlab?

Tags: matlab

for instance,

k = menu('a','b','c');

then I can insert a=amplitude in the pop up menu

Can I know basically how it can be done? Hmm...Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean a legend for a menu? It seems completely redundant. What do you want the legend to say?

Comment: @Dan Erm or what if I want to reselect the option in the 'menu' function, is it possible to add a 'Back' or 'Next' button in the pop up menu using matlab..hmmm...thank you.....